# Xcode 7 - An error has occurred during export - IPA has no main bundle

Tags: ios, bundle, xcode7, xcode-organizer, app-distribution

After archiving successfully my app using a mobile provisioning profile for ad-hoc distribution, when I try to export it using the Organizer window in Xcode, I get a strange message "An error has occurred during export, IPA has no main bundle".

[image]

Anyone? Any idea?

Comment: have you added all app icons?

Comment: yes, they are in the asset catalog

Comment: did you check the app plist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone will have the same issue, for me the problem was that I had a script responsible of customizing the Info.plist file. Unfortunately the script was saving the plist file in the binary format, instead of the plain text one. The result is that it looks identical in Xcode, the application will build fine, but archiving will fail.